# Is it safe to call thread.start() if the thread is in TERMINATED state?

Tags: java, thread-safety, java-threads

A thread that I am running in my web application returns `TERMINATED` when I call the `thread.getState()`

Is it safe for me to check the status through `thread.isAlive()` and call the `thread.start()` on a new object of the same class?

What should be the value of `thread.isAlive()` for me to start the terminated thread again?

Comment: If you want to restart a thread immediately after a previous one has stopped, and the two threads are doing the same thing, why let the first thread stop in the first place, and not just use a loop doing the same thing again and again, in a single thread?

Comment: The first thread has reached TERMINATED state and at this point, I am unable to figure it out why. I run a timer to check the status and call the start method, which I wanted to know about.

Answer (score 1):

I see threads as disposable/one-shot workers, they do a simple job and then they get killed.

The TERMINATED state is associated with an object. As long as you're using `start()` on a different (new) object, it's fine.